# HtmlAgilityPack with XPath - retrieve nodes that doesn't contain &nbsp;

Tags: c#, html, xpath

I'm trying to retrieve a select amount of elements that **doesn't** contain the value `&nbsp;` (a space) using the HtmlAgilityPack in C#. Here's my XPath expression:

```
"(td)[(position() >= 10 and position() <= last()) and not(.='&nbsp;')]"
```

but it is still giving me these nodes, I've tried using a literal space, `&#160;` ALT + 1060 - nothing seems to work. Here is what I'm parsing:

```
 <tr height=20 style='mso-height-source:userset;height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl96 style='height:15.0pt'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl97>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl106 style='border-top:none'>JIM COCKS</td>
  <td class=xl107 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl107 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl107 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>HOL</td>
  <td class=xl76>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl103 style='border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl97>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>09:30</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td> 
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>17:00</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl104 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl76>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
```

The items with the class 'xl104' is what I want to grab (I've done this with position statements as their classes change) but I only want nodes that contain something other than `&nbsp;`, e.g. the 09:30 AND 17:00 you see above.

Comment: Yuk.  That HTML is pretty invalid.  If you're generating it, you should clean it up.  If you're stuck with it because you are not generating it, good luck!

Comment: @Stephen - the HTML Agility Pack deals quite well with malformed HTML. And this fragment looks OK, HTML wise.

Comment: I'll concede that "HTML Agility Pack deals quite well with malformed HTML" as I know no better.  However, this fragment does not look OK.  Missing quotes around the class attribute values, single quotes around the style attribute values, proprietary "mso-height-source" Microsoft Office CSS attribute...  At least the table seems to represent tabular data.

Comment: @Stephen - unfortunately it's being generated by Excel 2007. Html Agility Pack does seem to handle it quite well though, I can still do XPath expressions on the attributes. For example, I do this further up: "//tr[@height='20'][count(td)=46]")

Comment: @Stephen - those are all fine in early HTML standards. Attribute values do not have to be quoted, single quotes are also fine, unknown CSS styles are also OK. HTML is a very forgiving standard.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and a solution. :)

Comment: @Oded: meh.  HTML attribute values have required quotes since HTML 4.01.  Are you really going to advocate HTML 3, (a.k.a. *Wilbur* http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/wilbur/), after it has been supplanted for over 13 years?

Comment: @Stephen - All I am saying is that excel produces HTML 3...

Comment: @Oded - Wow you're right.  I just tested it.  I guess my beef is with Microsoft.  As usual.

Comment: @eth0 - If you are in control of the excel file, have you thought about generating a simple .csv and parsing that?  Might be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"(td)[(position() >= 10 and position() <= last()) and not(.='&nbsp;')]"
```

`not(.='&nbsp;')`

tests that the whole text() node is not the string `'&nbsp;'`.

**You want to use the XPath `contains()` function**:

```
not(contains(., '&#xA0;'))
```

Comment: Yeah, I was tempted to say that too. However his `td` elements appear to have &nbsp; as their whole text node value... nothing else. So it would be puzzling if this were indeed the problem.

Comment: That did the trick! I knew there was a contains() fn but it never crossed my mind to use it because, as LarsH said, all of the td elements _just_ have &nbsp; in them. Thanks anyway! :-)

Comment: @eth0, in light of this, I suspect your input XML is not what you think it is (i.e. not what you showed above). Extra whitespace may have crept in. What happens when you select `string-length(td[10])`?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to retrieve a select amount
>   of elements that doesn't contain the
>   value `&nbsp;`

I believe @Dimitre has answered for that specification of the task.

> I only want nodes that contain
>   something other than `&nbsp;`

A slightly different specification. 
Does this work? (**Edited**; thanks to Alejandro.)

```
"td[position() >= 10 and translate(., '&#xA0;', '') != '']"
```

This is equivalent and shorter, but less readable:

```
"td[position() >= 10 and translate(., '&#xA0;', '')]"
```

Anyway, you found the problem so we won't go farther with this.

Do note, though, that using `&nbsp;` literally in XPath won't normally work unless you define it. This character entity is predefined in HTML but not in XML. That's why `&#160;` or `&#xA0;` is more reliable. However, it's possible that the HtmlAgilityPack defines   for you.

Comment: `fn:position()` result should always be less than or equal to `fn:last()`. Also, the boolean value of a string should be false if it's empty, and true otherwise. So, `td[position() >= 10 and translate(.,'&#A0;','')]`

Comment: @Alej: Thanks... to be honest I only looked at the part of the predicate related to nbsp. I'll edit my answer.